# Отправить JSON на сервер

Tags: json, ios, swift, post

Пытаюсь удаленно добавить новый продукт на сервис, запрос проходит успешно, но поле `category` всегда остается пустым, т.е. данные из шаблона не передаются. Что я делаю не так?

```
{
    code = 201;
    data =     {
        categories =         (
        );
        description = "Test Product description";
        "discount_amount" = "46644.03";
        id = 161;
        image = "https://loremflickr.com/250/250";
        name = DDDD;
        price = "49063.78";
        status = 1;
    };
    meta = "<null>";
}
```

Мой код:

```
struct Products: Decodable {
    var data: [Product]?
}

struct Product: Decodable, Hashable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var image: String?
    var price: String?
    var dicount_amount: String?
    var status: Bool?
    var categories: [Category]?
}

struct Categories: Decodable {
    var data: [Category]?
}

struct Category: Decodable, Hashable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var status: Bool?
}
```

```
func addProduct(name: String) {
        // Шаблон
        let userJson: [String : Any] = [
            "name": name,
            "description": "Test Product description",
            "image": "https://loremflickr.com/250/250",
            "price": "49063.78",
            "discount_amount": "46644.03",
            "status": true,
            "categories": [["id": 3, "name": "Computers & Toys"]]
        ]

        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userJson)
        
        let urlString = "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/products"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let token = "xxx"
        
        // POST request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, res, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No DATA")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(responseJSON)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: у вас есть тот вариант который должен быть для отправки? его можно сравнить с тем что передаете вы и я думаю найти ошибку. плюс возможно на той стороне что-то не срабатывает, попробуйте через какой-то постман например отправить

Comment: Я отправляю шаблон из метода adProduct(), по идее на сервисе gorest.co.in должна быть создана запись продукта с именем `name` и в разделе "Computers & Toys" появиться этот продукт, но продукт создается с пустым списком `categories`. Подозреваю что product и category связаны через  `product-categories`.

Comment: а там получается должен быть массив в массиве? просто немного странно выглядит [[

Answer (score 0):

По примеру у Вас массив объектов `Category`, а по тексту непонятно что:

```
"categories": [["id": 3, "name": "Computers & Toys"]]
```

Замените на:

```
"categories": [{"id": 3, "name": "Computers & Toys"}]
```

Ну и не может всё быть `optional`. Сделайте поля, которые не будут optional обязательными – это также поможет ловить некоторые проблемы за счёт fail-fast.